# Sorting months in sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I have a query like this

```
SELECT [Year], Month, AVG(salary) AS [salary] FROM table1 
    GROUP BY [Year],[Month]
    ORDER BY Year,Month
```

But the months are populated as jan, feb,... etc. When i say `order by month` I will be ordering them by letters. I was thinking if there is any scope like giving jan as 1, feb as 2 and so on and then sorting on the number

Comment: You have a table where month is text and got up voted?

Comment: If you have access to the date in an actual date format, look into `datepart()`

Comment: Blam - that is like storing numbers with names: Twohundredtwentyfive instead of 225

Comment: What is the values that the month is containing Jan or January?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to use following:

```
ORDER BY Year, CASE Month WHEN 'Jan' THEN 1 WHEN 'Feb' THEN 2 .... END
```

Fill in `....` with the rest of months.

Comment: How can you say that Its is stored as Jan but not January. I think you have to use Substring() for this to achieve if he is storing as January.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
ORDER BY convert(date, '01 ' + [Month] + ' ' + convert(varchar,[Year]) , 106)
```

Comment: Yup, or even without both the day part and a format specifier: `CAST(Month + ' ' + CAST(Year AS varchar) AS date)`.